# No difference in global python packages and virtualenv packages

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, virtualenv

I made a virtual environment using `virtualenv venv`

then I activated it with `source ./bin/activate`

It says that it's activated, but when I download a packages with pip3 (e.g. `pip3 install numpy`), it's available also in the global "package list", although I made the environment especially for the reason that I could have separate package lists with different projects.

after activating the virtual environment, when using `which pip3` the path is the same than if the virtual environment isn't activated.

Can you help me with this, I really tried to search for information with this kind of issues but couldn't manage to help myself.

br
t

Comment: Is your `virtualenv` install from python2 or python3? It might be that you're making a python2 virtual environment instead

Comment: hmm how should I define whether it's for python2 or python3? I just created it with above mentioned command.

Edit: and the virtualenv I downloaded with command ```pip3 install virtualenv```

Comment: When creating the virtualenv, it should list that it's creating a python3 executable: `New python executable in /my/dir/venv/bin/python3`. If that's not the case or it only says `python` and not `python3`, can you try creating the virtualenv using `python3 -m virtualenv venv` instead and see if that works?